# download excel by using Ajax andFlask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to download the excel from flask using Ajax call. it's showing the response code as 200 but excel is not downloading and the error messages are as follows.

Ajax Request :

$("#genExcel").on("click", function() {
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
                // Data to post
                var dataarray = {};

                // Use XMLHttpRequest instead of Jquery $ajax

                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    var a;
                    if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
                        // Trick for making downloadable link
                        a = document.createElement('a');
                        const objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhttp.response);
                        a.href = objectURL

                        //const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(object)

                        // Give filename you wish to download
                        a.download = "test-file.xlsx";
                        a.style.display = 'none';
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                    }
                };
                // Post data to URL which handles post request
                xhttp.open("POST", '/genexcel');
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                // You should set responseType as blob for binary responses
                //xhttp.responseType = 'blob';
                xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(dataarray));
            });
```

Flask function :

```
@app.route('/genexcel', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def createExcel():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json  
        # process json data        
        return send_file(strIO, attachment_filename='test.xlsx',  as_attachment=True)
```

Errors :

## 1 [Report Only] Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src * blob:".

## 2 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

```
at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange
```

[image: error and response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I've understood you correctly. Here is a very simple example using the data Array you provided. You could modify to suit your needs:

Flask Functions

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, send_file
import xlsxwriter

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/genexcel', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def createExcel():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        # process json data
        createExcel(data['data'])

    file_path = 'static/files/test.xlsx'
    return send_file(file_path, attachment_filename='test.xlsx', as_attachment=True)

def createExcel(data):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('static/files/test.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    row_no = 0
    col_no = 0
    for row in data:
        col_no = 0
        for entry in row:
            worksheet.write(row_no, col_no, entry)
            col_no += 1
        row_no += 1

    workbook.close()

app.run(debug=True, port=5010)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Testing
    <button id="genExcel">Direct Download</button>
    <button id="genExcelFlask">Flask Download</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("genExcel");
    var btnFlask = document.getElementById("genExcelFlask");
    var dataArray = {
      data: [
        [1, "A", 100],
        [2, "B", 200],
      ],
    };

    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then((resp) => resp.blob())
        .then((blob) => {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          a.style.display = "none";
          a.href = url;
          // the filename you want
          a.download = "todo-1.json";
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          alert("your file has downloaded!"); // or you know, something with better UX...
        })
        .catch(() => alert("oh no!"));
    });

    btnFlask.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(dataArray));

      fetch("{{ url_for('createExcel') }}", {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(dataArray),
      })
        .then((resp) => resp.blob())
        .then((blob) => {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          a.style.display = "none";
          a.href = url;
          // the filename you want
          a.download = "test.xlsx";
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          alert("your file has downloaded!"); // or you know, something with better UX...
        })
        .catch(() => alert("oh no!"));
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: @p-s-rao did that work for you? Did I understand your request properly?

Comment: after adding the headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } in fetch method it's working.  in flask function instead of physical path i'm keeping the file in memory and it's available to user. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the fetch API. The first button just does a straight JS download. The second button uses the Flask route to do the download. Hope it helps.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Testing
    <button id="genExcel">Direct Download</button>
    <button id="genExcelFlask">Flask Download</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("genExcel");
    var btnFlask = document.getElementById("genExcelFlask");

    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then((resp) => resp.blob())
        .then((blob) => {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          a.style.display = "none";
          a.href = url;
          // the filename you want
          a.download = "todo-1.json";
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          alert("your file has downloaded!"); // or you know, something with better UX...
        })
        .catch(() => alert("oh no!"));
    });

    btnFlask.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      fetch("{{ url_for('createExcel') }}")
        .then((resp) => resp.blob())
        .then((blob) => {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          a.style.display = "none";
          a.href = url;
          // the filename you want
          a.download = "test.xlsx";
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          alert("your file has downloaded!"); // or you know, something with better UX...
        })
        .catch(() => alert("oh no!"));
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Flask Function

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, send_file

@app.route('/genexcel', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def createExcel():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        print(data)
        # process json data

    file_path = 'static/files/test.xlsx'
    return send_file(file_path, attachment_filename='test.xlsx', as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: it's downloading the excel and it's showing warning msg as file is corrupted. in my code.. i'm passing the array to flask function and inserting that data into excel and then downloading it.
can you try to pass js array data to flask function and generate the excel from in-memory and not from physical location.?

Comment: So you want the JS to pass am array to the flask function. In that function you want to take the data passed to it and put it into a new excel file and then return the excel file to be downloaded... Is that correct? Do you have an example of the array data?

Comment: Yes.. i want to pass the array data and it should be inserted to excel on the fly and there is no need to read excel from physical path.example array is a nested array ex: dataArray=[[1,A,100],[2,B,200]] in output excel each array will be inserted into one row of excel.